# Python selenium decode iso-8859-1 to UTF-8

Tags: python, selenium, unicode, encoding, utf-8

Im using selenium to extract data from a web page.
Im trying to write this data into a file, but i have some trouble doing so, when i write special char like 'é' it create unreadable char in my file(Ã©).
The website im getting the page from is encoded in iso-8859-1 and im using python 2.7.

```
browser = webdriver.Firefox()  
browser.get(URL_SITE_ENCODED_IN_iso-8859-1)
html = browser.page_source.decode('iso-8859-1') //error
```

From what i understood i have to decode the page from iso-8859-1 then it will encode it in utf-8, but when i try to an error is raised : `UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe9' in position 246: ordinal not in range(128)`

Comment: Please provide the code that generates error, as described by: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Sorry i was busy yesterday night, i will edit that ^^

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's probably because `browser.page_source.decode` is already decoded Unicode. Check with:

```
>>> type(browser.page_source.decode)
<type 'unicode'>
```

When you write this to a file, you need to convert it to an appropriate encoding. In Python 2.x, use io module to create an automatic encoding file wrapper. Try:

```
browser = webdriver.Firefox()  
browser.get(anysite)

with io.open("myoutfile.txt", "w", encoding="utf-8") as my_file:
    my_file.write(browser.page_source)
```